# How many combinations and how to find a (standard?) distribution that matches?

Tags: distributions, combinatorics

Take a string ABCDE and insert dots in it according to these rules:

1. First and last character must not be a dot.
2. 0-4 dots
3. A dot may not follon upon another dot. In other words, a dot must always be preceded by a letter.

Valid strings:

```
ABCDE
AB.CD.E
A.B.C.D.E
```

Invalid strings:

```
.ABCDE
ABC..DE
```

With 0 dots, only one combination is possible (ABCDE), with 1 dot four combinations are possible (A.BCDE, AB.CDE and so on). With 2 dots I think there are 6 possible combinations:

```
A.B.CDE
A.BC.DE
A.BCD.E
AB.C.DE
AB.CD.E
ABC.D.E
```

3 dots:

```
A.B.C.DE
A.B.CD.E
A.BC.D.E
AB.C.D.E
```

4 dots - 1 combination.

If I made this right, the total number of combination with a 5 character long string to start with is 1 + 4 + 6 + 4 + 1 = 16 (for a 4 character string it is 8, 3 character -> 4). It seems the formula to calculate the number of possible combinations is 2^(n-1) where n is the number of characters in the initial string.

What kind of distribution is this? I want to create random numbers distributed like this (that is, if I draw 16 numbers between 0 and 4, on average 6 of them must be 2, 4 of them 1, and 4 of them 3 and so on) in Java.

And, if you have a longer string (the actual string I work with is 16 letters), how do you calculate the number of combinations you get if you, e.g., insert 5 dots into these 16 letters according to the rules above?

Comment: You may be looking for [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle). If you consider the spaces between chars as a unit that you allocate dots to, it seems a plain combinatorics problem that need not rely on any  probability distributions (unless you really make it to).

Comment: While I did say "need not rely on any probability distribution", it is, of course, _connected_ to the binomial distribution with p=1/2.

Comment: @B.Liu The reason I asked for a probability distribution is that I want to generate strings with a random number of dots as input for something I am working on.

Comment: @B.Liu Pascal's Triangle was exactly right! I know I had read about sometime in high school a long time ago. Now I just wonder how I can create random numbers using that?

Comment: It depends on what "random numbers" you are referring to. If you are generating the _number_ of dots $k$ to put in a string with length $n$, then sampling from $Bin(n-1, 1/2)$ (i.e. binomial distribution with $n-1$ trials and success probability 1/2) should work. If you know what $k$ is and want to generate the _positions_ of the dots, randomly taking $k$ elements from the list [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1] should get what you want. The exact implementation depends on the programming language you are using, but in Python you can use `numpy`, and R supports the operations natively.

Answer (score 1):

With 5 letters there are 4 positions for dots $\sum_{i=0}^4 {4\choose i} = 1+4+6+4+1 = 16 = 2^4.$

In general, if I understand your problem correctly, with $n$ letters there are $n=1$ potential locations for $0$ through $n-1$ dots, and the number of possibilities is $2^{n-1}.$

The identity $\sum_{i=0}^m {m\choose i} = 2^m.$ is proved from the binomial theorem $(a+b)^m = \sum_{i=0}^m {m\choose i}a^ib^{m-i},$ by letting $a=b=1.$

Intuitively, the number of subsets of a set with $m$ elements (including 'improper' null subset and whole set itself) is $2^m$ because there are two choices for each element--*in* or *out.* Also, there are ${m\choose i}$ subsets of order $i.$

Answer (score 1):

The questions appears to be a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You asked in the question "What kind of distribution is this [the number of dots in a string of length $n$]?", and "how I can create random numbers [the number of dots] using that [the distribution]?" but from the comments, you actually wanted to "generate strings with a random number of dots as input for something I am working on", with the random number of dots following the said distribution.

We will address both questions here, perhaps using a more procedural, CS-friendly perspective (spoiler: the solution to the second problem is easier than the first).

#### Inserting $k$ dots is a "$n$ choose $k$" problem

Consider a string with $n+1$ characters, the rules you gave mean that one can either insert zero or one dot for each of the $n$ "space" between characters. If one were to insert $k \in \{0, ..., n\}$ dots in total, the number of ways to do that is $\binom{n}{k}$, or "$n$ choose $k$".

#### If all possible combinations are equal, the chance of seeing $k$ dots follows a binomial distribution:

Across all possible values of $k$, one would have $ \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + ... \binom{n}{n} = 2^n $ possible ways to insert the dots. The chance in seeing a way with $k$ dots inserted is

$$ \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n} = \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}, $$

which is the probability mass function for a binomial distribution with $n$ trials and a success probability of 1/2. It is not a coincidence - it is a common way binomial distributions are constructed.

#### You can generate the random strings in a 2-step process...

You are then interested in creating random numbers, presumably the number of dots, so that they can generate strings with the said number of dots for downstream applications.

Given the above, one way to do it is:

1. Generating the number of dots $k$: this can be done by taking a sample from $Bin(n,1/2)$ (i.e. binomial distribution with $n$ trials and success probability 1/2).
2. Given $k$, generate the positions of the dots, randomly taking $k$ elements from the list/array [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1] should get what you want.

The random samples are easily obtainable in many programming languages - Java has `Java.util.Random`, Python has `numpy.random`, and R does that natively.

#### ...but generating them in one step is cooler.

However, you are actually interested in generating the strings with dots in random location (or at least you appear to be interested). This means the value of $k$ doesn't really matter as long as it fits the binomial distribution in the long run.

In this case, we should take a step back, and recall we can get a random $k$ that follows a binomial distribution by flipping a fair coin $n$ times, and count how many time it landed on heads (which we denote by `1`, and `0` otherwise).

The good news is, you now have a sequence of `0`s and `1`s for free:

- Each sequence of length $n$ are equally likely to be generated, and thus for a known $k$ we will have $\binom{n}{k}$ equally likely sequences with $k$ `1`s that does the random choice for us. This is done by taking the indices of the `1`s. Step 2 above sorted.
- We also established above that the number of `1`s in a randomly generated sequence follows the binomial distribution. This means Step 1 above is also sorted.

The even better news? You can generate such a sequence quickly with a (pseudo) random number generator - for a sequence of length $n$, one simply needs to generate a random integer between $0$ and $2^n - 1$ and convert the generated integer into its binary representation.

In short, if you have has a string with 16 characters, they will generate a random integer between $0$ and $32767$, say $19342$. $19342$ has a binary representation of `100101110001110`, and thus you will insert a dot after the 0th, 3rd, 5th, 6th, ... characters to get a string with random dots inserted. The number of dots will then follow the binomial distribution in the long run.

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted. I can give you some more background, just because you made an effort. In GMail, if you have the e-mailaddress abcde@gmail.com, a.bcde@gmail, a.b.c.d.e@gmail (and so on) all end up at abcde@gmail.com. Of course, a....bcde@gmail.com and (I think) a.bcde..@gmail.com also go to abcde@gmail.com but are more likely to be caught by stupid e-mailaddress validation filters. My goal is to create, randomly, as many unique addresses as possible, without a need to store already used addresses. (cont)

Comment: (cont). And if you randomly, with the same probability, pick 0 to 4 dots, you are more likely to create an already used address when picking 0 and 4 (because there is only one possibility) than when picking 2 dots. Therefore I want higher probability for 2 dots than for 0/4 dots. Thank you.

Comment: @d-b I see... in this case, I wonder if generating all $2^n$ possible email usernames from a string of length $n+1$ and use them all in one go is an better option? Alternatively, using a pseudo RNG with a periodicity of $2^n$ and keeping track of its state can also ensure you get all $2^n$ usernames unused?